# Jboss JBAS014750 - error deploying ear

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm having trouble deploying an ear to jboss.
I've searched the internets and the only reference was something about socket bindings, but I'm using the default **standalone-full** cfg.

Any ideas about the **JBAS014750**?

```
18:06:16,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver cl
ass org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver (version 10.5)
18:06:17,116 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossor
g-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/fce'
18:06:19,147 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
18:06:21,085 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /fce
18:06:21,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "fce-application.ear
" was rolled back with failure message JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete
18:06:21,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fce-module-ejb.jar in
99ms
18:06:21,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fce-module-core-servi
ces.jar in 99ms
18:06:21,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fce-module-presentatio
n.war in 645ms
18:06:24,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fce-application.ear in
 2817ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had an incorrectly configured data source. My bad.